# How do I get newly created documents to end up in correct folders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document, document-template

I've got quite a complex document library, with some folders that have strict access for certain users. I've created a content type and will add templates to the content type.

If i clicke my way down to a certain folder in my SharePoint library then choose to create a new document from a template, and then save it, is doesn't end up in the folder i had selected, it's saved on the top folder, not in the folder I was in when I opened a new document.

How do I get my documents to end up in the chosen folder in my library, without having to choose the correct one when i'm saving my document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Content Organizer could be useful in this case ?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-the-content-organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a

If not then I suppose you will need a custom Remote Event Receiver:

https://www.tatvasoft.com.au/blog/how-to-implement-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Content organizer and rules, will do some research into that and try it out. Thanks!